# Removing items in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I've got a loop in a button action for removing empty items in my `ListView`, but the problem is, when I press the button it deletes successfully only the items that were single. I mean: it does not remove items, when there are few one after another:

example:

```
a1 = ""
a2 = "qwe"
a3 = ""
a4 = ""
a5 = "qwe"
```

so, after button click, the result will be:

```
a2 = "qwe"
a3(or a4 idk) = ""
a5 = "qwe"
```

I think it's easy logic problem, but I can't figure it out.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++) 
            {
                if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text == "")
                {
                    listView1.Items[i].Remove();
                }
            }
```

So the problem is that the loop skips one check after it finds the empty value.
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When removing items in a `for loop`, loop *backward*:

```
for (int i = listView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
  if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text == "")
    listView1.Items[i].Remove();
```

or modify the for loop into

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; ) // no ++i here
  if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text == "")
    listView1.Items[i].Remove();
  else  
    i += 1; // ...but it's here
```

This is a common principle beyond `ListView` items. See what's getting on: imagine that you want remove `A` from the collection

```
  [A, A, B, A]
```

when you've found that's 0th item must be deleted, you *should not increment* counter after deletion, but test *new* 0th item *again*.

Comment: Smart. Thank you very much!